# Como faço para esperar até que uma condição é dada no LOVE2D?

Tags: lua

Eu ja tentei

```
timer=require'hump.timer'
    timer.script(function(wait)
    repeat
        wait(0)
    until condição
```

mas não funcionou.Eu até tentei retirar o `wait`,mas o jogo crashou.Por favor me ajudem!!!

Answer (score 0):

A função [`wait`](https://github.com/vrld/hump/blob/master/timer.lua#L95) faz uso de coroutines, então isso deveria funcionar normalmente. Ou já tentou usar [`timer.every`](http://hump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timer.html#Timer.every)?

```
timer.every(0, function()
    if condição then
        --[=[ Ação final ]=]
        -- Acaba por aqui.
        return;
    end
    return true;
end);
```

Ou:

```
timer.every(0, function()
    --[=[ Ação enquanto isso não acaba ]=]
    return not condição;
end);
```